Persisting error state in react-query until successful refetch
I'm using React Query to fetch a list of users via the useQuery hook. When the fetch fails, I display an error message along with a retry button. When I call refetch, both isError and error are immediately reset to false and null. This results in the error message disappearing momentarily, which I want to avoid.
Is there a way to persist the error state in React Query until the data is successfully fetched without using additional React useState to track the error manually? Ideally, I'd like to keep everything managed with react-query.
Any suggestions or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
    const { data, isLoading, isFetching, isError, refetch } = getUsers();

    if (isError) {
        return (
            <div className='border border-neutral-200 py-8 px-4 rounded-md text-center'>
                <div>
                    <Typography variant='base' as='h1' weight={500} className='text-black'>
                        Oh no, something went wrong!
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant='small' as='h1' weight={500} className='text-black'>
                        Sorry, we ran into an issue fetching the information. A quick retry might solve it.
                    </Typography>
                </div>
                <div className='mt-4'>
                    <Button impact='light' color='blue' onClick={() => refetch()} className='inline-flex px-4'>
                        {isFetching ? <Icon name='Loader' className='animate-spin' /> : 'Retry'}
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }


I think react-query changes the value of isRefetching to true, and isError to false when you call refetch().
Why not try using error instead of isError?

That’s correct - React Query sets isRefetching to true, isError to false. error is being set to null when refetch() is called. My question is whether there’s a way to persist the error state until a successful fetch is completed, or if I need to handle this outside react-query.
